# Lotus Notes Domino Getting Date Difference

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have made a code using lotusscript that would calculate the time difference between the two fields, now I want to calculate the difference between dates. I've pretty much started lotusscripting and I still got a minimum knowledge about it. Hope you can help me. Here's the code that I've made to calculate time difference:

```
Sub UpdateDuration()
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim starttime As NotesDateTime
Dim endtime As NotesDateTime
Dim duration As Integer

Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
If uidoc.FieldGetText("StartTime") = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Elseif uidoc.FieldGetText("StartTime") = "" Then
    Exit Sub        
End If
Set starttime = New NotesDateTime( uidoc.FieldGetText("StartTime") )
Set endtime = New NotesDateTime( uidoc.FieldGetText("EndTime") )
duration = endtime.TimeDifference( starttime )
Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Duration", Cstr(duration) )
Call uidoc.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TimeDifference returns the number of seconds between two NotesDateTimes.  There are 60 * 60 * 24 seconds in a day, and that works out to 86400.  So just write your code exactly as above and divide the result by 86400.  (The only other thing you might want to change is your field and variable names, to reflect the fact that you are working with date input instead of time.)

Comment: thanks alot @Richard. My code is now outputting dates. I learned alot from you.

Comment: Also - you'll need to Dim your duration as Long, instead of Integer.  Otherwise you'll get an overflow if they're even half a day apart.